Consult the results from query
I want to get only the peoples names that arrived early 5+ days
--- SCRIPT VERSION 2.0 (Get the dates of the people that are in time)----

-- Subconsulta de entrada
WITH Entrada AS (
    SELECT ID, PersonName, AuthDate, min(AuthTime) as AuthTime
    --,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, AuthDate ORDER BY AuthTime ASC) AS RowNum
    FROM HR_Timing
    WHERE DeviceName = 'HR' 
      AND AuthDate BETWEEN '2024-11-18' AND '2024-11-22'
      AND AuthTime <= '08:00:00'
      --ORDER BY CAST(ID as INT) ASC, AuthDate ASC, AuthTime ASC
      group by ID, PersonName, AuthDate
),
-- Subconsulta de salida
Salida AS (
    SELECT ID, PersonName, AuthDate, max(AuthTime) as AuthTime
    --ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonName, AuthDate ORDER BY AuthTime ASC) AS RowNum
    FROM HR_Timing
    WHERE DeviceName = 'HR' 
        AND AuthDate BETWEEN '2024-11-18' AND '2024-11-22'
        AND AuthTime >= '20:00:00'
    --ORDER BY CAST(ID as INT) ASC, AuthDate ASC, AuthTime ASC
    group by ID, PersonName, AuthDate
)

-- Realizar los JOINs
SELECT 
    CAST(Entrada.ID as INT) AS Entrada_ID,
    Entrada.PersonName AS Entrada_PersonName,
    Entrada.AuthDate AS Entrada_AuthDate,
    Entrada.AuthTime AS Entrada_AuthTime,
    Salida.AuthTime AS Salida_AuthTime,
    Salida.AuthDate AS Salida_AuthDate,
    Salida.ID AS Salida_ID,
    Salida.PersonName AS Salida_PersonName
FROM Entrada
INNER JOIN Salida
    ON Entrada.ID = Salida.ID
   AND Entrada.AuthDate = Salida.AuthDate
  /* WHERE ENTRADA.RowNum = 1
   AND SALIDA.RowNum = 1  */
ORDER BY Entrada_ID ASC, Entrada.AuthDate ASC, Entrada.AuthTime ASC;


I've tried to declare it and then consult it but seems like I have an issue with the "WITH" bucle

When you say "consult it" what do you mean? I don't think its translating correctly, because its not a normal term in this arena.

I suggest providing a complete [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Calculate the earliest arrival time and latest exit time for each person on each day to get a consolidated view of their daily activity.
Introduce a CASE expression to flag early arrivals to filter for early arrivals later.
Select distinct PersonName from EarlyArrivals where IsEarlyArrival is 1 (meaning they arrived early).
Use GROUP BY PersonName to group the results by person.
Use HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT AuthDate) >= 5 condition to ensure that only people included are those who arrived early on at least 5 different days.
WITH DailyEntries AS (
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        PersonName, 
        AuthDate,
        MIN(AuthTime) AS EarliestArrivalTime,
        MAX(AuthTime) AS LatestExitTime
    FROM HR_Timing
    WHERE DeviceName = 'HR' 
      AND AuthDate BETWEEN '2024-11-18' AND '2024-11-22'
    GROUP BY ID, PersonName, AuthDate
),
EarlyArrivals AS (
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        PersonName, 
        AuthDate,
        EarliestArrivalTime,
        LatestExitTime,
        CASE 
            WHEN EarliestArrivalTime <= '08:00:00' THEN 1  -- Arrival before 8:00 AM
            ELSE 0 
        END AS IsEarlyArrival
    FROM DailyEntries
)
SELECT DISTINCT PersonName
FROM EarlyArrivals
WHERE IsEarlyArrival = 1
GROUP BY PersonName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT AuthDate) >= 5;

Avoid copy-pasting.

What do you mean by avoid copy and pasting?

Wow, what kind of question is that? Means you need to read, understand and then implement, instead of mere copy-pasting.

Wow, what kind of question is that? I guess the same as all questions, obvious to the person who knows, not necessarily obvious to everyone else 

This worked very well, thanks a lot

you're welcome
